# Streaming audio from avconv via NodeJs WebSockets into Chrome with AudioContext

Tags: node.js, audio, websocket, avconv, webkitaudiocontext

we're having trouble playing streamed audio in a browser (using Chrome).

We have a process which is streaming some audio (for example an internet radio) on udp on some port. It's avconv (`avconv -y -i SOMEURL -f alaw udp://localhost:PORT`). 
We have a NodeJs server which receives this audio stream and forwards it to multiple clients connected via websockets. The audio stream which NodeJs receives is wrapped in a buffer which is an array with numbers from 0 to 255. The data is sent to the browser without any issues and then we're using AudioContext to play the audio stream in the browser (our code is based on AudioStreamer - https://github.com/agektmr/AudioStreamer).

At first, all all we got at this point was static. When looking into the AudioStreamer code, we realized that the audio stream data should be in the -1 to 1 range. With this knowledge we tried modifying each value in the buffer with this formula `x = (x/128) - 1`. We did it just to see what would happen and surprisingly the static became a bit less awful - you could even make out melodies of songs or words if the audio was speech. But it's still very very bad, lots of static, so this is obviously not a solution - but it does show that we are indeed receiving the audio stream via the websockets and not just some random data.

So the question is - what are we doing wrong? Is there a codec/format we should be using? Of course all the code (the avconv, NodeJs and client side) can be modified at will. We could also use another browser if needed, though I assume that's not the problem here. The only thing we do know is that we really need this to work through websockets.

The OS running the avconv and NodeJs is Ubuntu (various versions 10-13)

Any ideas? All help will be appreciated.

Thanks!
Tomas

Answer (score 0):

The conversion from integer samples to floating point samples is incorrect.  You must take into account:

- Number of channels
- Number of bits per sample
- Signed/unsigned
- Endianess

Let's assume you have a typical WAV file at 16 bit stereo, signed, little-endian.  You're on the right track with your formula, but try this:

```
x = (x/32768) - 1
```